# Handle ToggleButton in onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, back-stack, android-togglebutton

I have written a program in which I am using `Timer` and controlling that timer using `Toggle` states.

`Toggle's` default state is `OFF`, once I make changes in toggle state from `OFF` to `ON` `Timer` starts, and when I again change to `OFF` it stops the `Timer` as per requirement.

But problem starts when my `Timer` is `ON` and I switch to other activity and then again `come back` to `ToggleActivity` and then do changes in toggle state from `ON` to `OFF` - it still runs `Timer`...

**Note:** when I use `finish()` or `back` press, in place of `Intent` to come back to `ToggleActivity` everything works fine, but when I use `Intent` facing such issues..

**ToggleActivity.java:**

```
public class ToggleActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    TextView text;

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Button btnSwitchActivity;

    boolean toggleState;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toggle);           

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnSwitchActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchActivity);

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("toggleState",0);

        btnSwitchActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intentSwitchActivity = new Intent(ToggleActivity.this, SwitchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSwitchActivity);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {      

            if(isChecked)
            {               
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleState", true);
                editor.commit();

                text.setText("ON");

                startTimer();

            } else 
            {       

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleState", false);
                editor.commit();

                text.setText("OFF");

                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }

        }


        public void startTimer() {

            timer = new Timer();            
            initializeTimerTask();          
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 5000);

        }

        public void stoptimertask(View v) {

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }

        }

        public void initializeTimerTask() {

            timerTask = new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                            final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;  
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }

                    });

                }

            };

        }

        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            toggleState = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleState", false);
            Log.v("toggleState", Boolean.toString(toggleState));

            if (toggleState) {
                toggleButton.setChecked(true);
                text.setText("ON");
            } else {
                toggleButton.setChecked(false);
                text.setText("OFF");
            }

            toggleButton.setChecked(toggleState);
            toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);         
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();             
            toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
          } 

}
```

**SwitchActivity.java**

```
public class SwitchActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnToggleActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);

        btnToggleActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToggleActivity);
        btnToggleActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(SwitchActivity.this, ToggleActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                /**
                 * if i use finish instead of Intent to switch to ToggleActivity 
                 * my Timer works fine
                 */
                // finish
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**activity_toggle.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ToggleActivity" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/string_toggle_off"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitchActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_btn_switch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_switch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnToggleActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_btn_goback"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the `setText` behave correctly (ie as you would expect the time to), or does is misbehave like the time does?

Comment: @NeilTownsend check my updated code and screens

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use finish? That would seem to be the correct approach in the absence of a good reason not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"But problem starts when my Timer is ON and I switch to other activity and then again come back to Toggle activity"...*

You DO not come back. As @Fabin Paul mentioned you just create a new instance of `ToggleActivity`. So in the scenario when you launch the app, then move to `SwitchActivity` and back by clicking the button, the [back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) looks as follows:

**`ToggleActivity(1) -> SwitchActivity -> ToggleActivity(2)`**

*"...and then do changes in toggle state from ON to OFF - it still runs Timer..."*

You switch off the timer of the second instance of ToggleActivity. The one that is running belongs to the first ToggleActivity's instance.

*"when I use finish(); or back press, in place of Intent to come back to ToggleActivity everything works fine..."*

Yes, it does, because you don't create the second instance of `ToggleActivity` and your logic works correctly.

The easiest way to get the desired behavior is to add [`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) to the ToggleActivity's tag of the manifest.

Comment: This is the core issue. I would only add that the other solution would be to use finish, as you note in the updated question.

Comment: @Onik incredible :) you are master.. thanks to each and every one who helped me

Answer (score 0):

When the `ToggleActivity` switches to `onPause` state, it doesn't cancel the running `Timer`. You need to cancel it manually.

You can add the following code snippet within your `onPause()` method:

```
if (timerTask != null)
    timerTask.cancel();
if (timer != null) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to cancel the timer

Comment: but you said, It keeps running, that's your problem ?

Comment: Then do one thing Add above code in your stoptimertask(View v) function. And give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because for each instance of activity an instance of timer is created. So when you press stop only one instance of timer is stopped while the background activity's timer instance is not stopped.

I got around the problem by making timer static

```
static Timer timer;
```

and starting only one instance of the timer

```
public void startTimer() {
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 5000);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: `if (toggleState) {
   toggleButton.setChecked(true);
   text.setText("ON");
  } else {
   text.setText("OFF");
   toggleButton.setChecked(false);
  }``

Comment: text visibility is not the issue, matter is when i do toggle off it runs timer

Answer (score -1):

here you are calling `setChecked(true)` means `onCheckedChangeListener` will call,then updating the preference also, you have to remove the listener and set listener to the toggle button,like this:

```
toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
toggleMap.setChecked(isChecked);
toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

**EDIT**

```
    @Override
         protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            tg1pref = preferences.getBoolean("tg1pref", false);
            toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            toggleMap.setChecked(tg1pref);
            toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

               if (!tg1pref) {
                    if (timer != null) {
                         timer.cancel();
                          timer = null;
                        }   
                }
}
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: please check my posted code, still getting same issue

Comment: still not working, even not saving state of toggle bro

Comment: remove onCheckedChangeLister in onPause()method.

Comment: bro i am not using onPause() i tried your way even not saving toggle state

Comment: i edited my answer check it once, unfortunately i removed one line in between lister setting functionality.

Comment: let's check my updated code, and now you may earn 100 as bounty

Answer (score -1):

Assign the listener to the toggle button after checking the state.

Just remove:

```
toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

line in `onCreate` and add the same line in `onResume` after updating the status.

```
toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

and in `onPause()`:

```
toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    tg1pref = preferences.getBoolean("tg1pref", false);
    if (!tg1pref) {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }   
    }
    toggleMap.setChecked(tg1pref);
    toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

and:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    toggleMap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
}
```

Comment: i am confuse can you show me where i have to put in onResume() and why in onPause() ?

Comment: is it worked out first tell me then i will explain the scenario.

Comment: hey... for a while it shows exact status, but after that same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69288/discussion-between-sun-and-no-name).

Comment: let's check my updated code, and now you may earn 100 as bounty