# Handle Toggle States in onResume() using Intent and SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timer, sharedpreferences

I have written a program in which i am using Timer and controlling that timer using Toggle states,

Like: My Toggle's default state is OFF, once i make changes in toggle state from OFF to ON TIMER starts, and when i again change to OFF it stops the timer as per requirement.

But problem starts when my Timer is ON and I switch to other activity and then again come back to Toggle activity and then do changes in toggle state from ON to OFF - it still runs Timer...

**ToggleActivity.java:**

```
public class ToggleActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    TextView text;

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Button btnSwitchActivity;

    boolean toggleState;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toggle);           

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnSwitchActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchActivity);

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("toggleState",0);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        btnSwitchActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intentSwitchActivity = new Intent(ToggleActivity.this, SwitchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSwitchActivity);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {      

            if(isChecked)
            {               
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleState", true);
                editor.commit();

                text.setText("ON");

                startTimer();

            } else 
            {       

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleState", false);
                editor.commit();

                text.setText("OFF");

                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }

        }


        public void startTimer() {

            timer = new Timer();            
            initializeTimerTask();          
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 5000);

        }

        public void stoptimertask(View v) {

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }

        }

        public void initializeTimerTask() {

            timerTask = new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                            final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;  
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }

                    });

                }

            };

        }

        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            toggleState = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleState", false);
            Log.v("toggleState-onResume()", Boolean.toString(toggleState));
            if (toggleState) {
                toggleButton.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }

        }

}
```

**SwitchActivity.java:**

```
public class SwitchActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnToggleActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);

        btnToggleActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToggleActivity);
        btnToggleActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(SwitchActivity.this, ToggleActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                /**
                 * if i use finish() instead of Intent to switch to ToggleActivity 
                 * my Timer works fine
                 */
                // finish
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_toggle.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ToggleActivity" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/string_toggle_off"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitchActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_btn_switch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_switch.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnToggleActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_btn_goback"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try  to remove your code from `onResume()` and add in `onCreate()`

Comment: what's wrong here, why it has been downvoted ?

Comment: Sorry!! but i am not!!!!

Comment: @MD tried but not done .. this is difficult to resolve, can you try at your end ?

Comment: have you logged the preference value ?

Comment: yes i have logged the preference value, its very tedious task ... :(

Comment: sorry i have given it a try, but facing same issue, i agree that's really difficult, but i am still trying to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You should probably save the state of the toggle button in the savedInstanceState bundle by overriding onSaveInstanceState.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outstate.putBoolean("KEY", yourButton.isToggle())
    }
```

And then you can access it by reading the savedInstanceState bundle given to you in onCreate of your activity or onCreateView/onViewCreated if you work in a fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not getting, please make changes in my posted code, and you may earn 100 bounty once you will done with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061651/handle-toggle-button-in-onresume